# Firefox and Internet explorer mp4 playback issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, ffmpeg, html5-video

I use a tool for recording desktop videos.

I use the same settings in the tool and same resolution and record two different videos.

http://www.mindmigma.com/users/fb-fac3b0ok/video3.mp4
http://www.mindmigma.com/users/fb-fac3b0ok/video4.mp4

Both of those videos can be played with Google Chrome version 31.

But only video3.mp4 can be played with Firefox version 27 and Internet Explorer 11

When i make videos it feels like a random pattern if a video will be playable or not. How can this be is the video4.mp4 damaged somehow?

It feels so wierd when you use the same settings and its an 50% chance the video will play in Firefox and IE.

Would be really glad if i could get some help.
Thanks in advance!

/Marten S

Comment: The second video is not playing for me even in Chrome. I am using version 31.
So please cross check that the that there is noting wrong with the second video.

Comment: You mention that you use "a tool" but you did not specify what tool you are using and how you are using it (the commands and complete console outputs would be useful). Also, questions not about programming are offtopic here. Your question can be migrated to [su].

Comment: What tool are you using? I'm seeing similar strangeness with IE 11 after encoding with FFMPEG. Still looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

As LordNeckbeard suggested: Super User has the answer:

quick fix: Set your security level to Normal (standard is Normal-High).

for more detailed information check Super User:
https://superuser.com/questions/916958/play-mp4-video-in-internet-explorer-11-with-security-level-set-to-high

I just thought I'd share because I lost a lot of time looking for this.